# Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Indic_General_90_BIN" in the concat operation

Tags: sql, concatenation

below is my code,

```
SELECT [ItemCode], CONCAT([ItemCode] , [ItemDescription]) as ID_Name FROM PosItem
ORDER BY [ItemCode]
```

but as i saw CONCAT brings below error. Please help  to solve this. Thanks.

Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Indic_General_90_BIN" in the concat operation

Comment: Can you post the definition of your table PosItem? To me it appears that [ItemCode]  and  [ItemDescription] columns have been defined with different collations.

Comment: ItemCode is varchar(30) & ItemDescription is nvarchar(200)